# Fixed block elements

Tags: html, css, layout

i try make some parts of page with "fixed" style. I have similar HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="frame">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div class="toolbar">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="left-panel">
                <ul>
                    <li>Test 1</li>
                    <li>Test 2</li>
                    <li>Test 3</li>
                    <li>Test 4</li>
                    <li>Test 5</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="content-fluid">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br /> 
                consectetur adipisicing elit, sed <br />
                do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore<br />
                 et dolore magna aliqua. 
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .frame {
        border: none;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    .frame td {
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .toolbar {
        heigth: 40px;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    .left-panel {
        width: 150px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: yellow;   
    }

    .content-fluid {
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
</style>
```

How make .toolbar and .left-panel fixed and center. I try add style fixed and negative margin. It works, but i dont think that this right solution. And i also use table for frame (i dont know how to center it in another way (.content-fluid should stretch)) and it looks ugly.
sorry for my bad english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make your Table Center you can set ".Container" width to 100% and add "margin:auto" to your frame. Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/KNdw5/

About your first question, would you please explain more?

Comment: thank you, i forgot to add margins.
I want yellow and blue blocks with "position: fixed" would remain in the same places (center aligned). Only block .content-fluid should scroll.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Mzzgs/7/
but blue block should be stretched. and perhaps, if possible?, without using table.

Comment: I hope this helps: http://jsfiddle.net/Mzzgs/12/  
I change it to table-less and also make your Blue block fixed on top and stretched and center aligned. And yellow block also fixed on left-side. I'm not sure if that's what you wanted or want me to apply other changes?

Comment: thanks, it's almost what i wanted. i will try to do changes needed for me